# bundle install gives undefined method `ruby' for #<Bundler::Dsl:0x00000001c4e1f8>

Tags: ruby, bundler

`bundle install` is giving:

```
> undefined method `ruby' for #<Bundler::Dsl:0x00000001c4e1f8>
```

Any idea how to fix? I'm using Ruby 1.9.3-p125.

Comment: You should probably provide your Gemfile.

Answer (score 19):

Version 1.2 of [Gembundler](http://gembundler.com/) introduced a [`ruby` method to the dsl](http://gembundler.com/v1.2/gemfile_ruby.html) that allows you to specify the Ruby version your app should use.

It looks like the `Gemfile` you’re using was written for this new version, but the version of bundler you have doesn’t support the `ruby` method. You need to either install the latest bundler (`gem install bundler` should do it) or remove the line from your `Gemfile`.

Answer (score 5):

Run these commands the problem will fix

step 1: install bundler
                **gem install bundler**

step 2: **bundle install**

it will fix the issue..

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `ruby 'something or other'` in your Gemfile.

This one-liner should find the offending line for you (note that you need to be in the same dir as the Gemfile, and the ca$h indicates the prompt -- on your system this may be `>`)

```
$ ruby -ne 'print "(line #$.) #$_" if /^\s*ruby/' Gemfile
```

Without understanding why you did this, I can't tell you what you should have done instead, but there is no `ruby` method as part of bundler's DSL.

You can see the DSL code [here](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/fa28ae9f3c1b8364547ac9b5dc76937923e202fb/lib/bundler/dsl.rb).

You can see Bundler's documentation [here](http://gembundler.com/), and the documentation for Gemfiles [here](http://gembundler.com/man/gemfile.5.html).

Answer (score 0):

You may be using an out-dated version of bundler

You can check the version of bundler you're using with

```
bundle --version
```

If it's older than version 1.2, it's probably outdated, based on [matt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11488907/38765).

In my case, I'd done `gem install bundler`, but forgot to do `rbenv rehash` (I use rbenv), and therefore it wasn't using the bundler I'd just installed, but an old, outdated version.